# Business Objects Webi "Use Custom SQL" Generation

Tags: business-objects

Is anyone aware of any tricks or object order that will modify the custom SQL that business objects creates? Currently we have requirements stating that we must only use the "custom SQL" generated by Business Objects. The problem with this SQL is it starts out with a Right outer join on a child table that is not our entry point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Business Objects has a super secret setting in the Universe Designer Properties. Inthe properties change the **SORT_JOINS_BY_QUERY_OBJECTS** to **YES**. This will make BOBJ generate the SQL using the order of your objects in the result objects pane.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL is determined via the Universe and the order of how the objects are dragged into the WebI doc does effect how BO generates that SQL.

It sounds like you are looking to change how the from clause is being built, which almost always requires a change in the Universe and not the order that objects are brought into the WebI query builder.

You may be able to get a better feel on how to change the universe to generate the correct/better SQL on [Dave Rathbun's blog](http://www.dagira.com/category/design/) most notably his articles on contexts.